# Download de um PDF recebido de uma API com AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tenho uma API que me retorna um arquivo PDF.

Quero fazer o angular bater nessa rota e forçar o download do arquivo PDF.

Hoje faço assim:

```
var blob = new Blob([arquivo], {type: "application/pdf"});
saveAs(blob, 'arquivo.pdf');
```

O download funciona, mas o arquivo pdf vem em branco.
Se eu bater na rota manualmente, o arquivo vem completo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Falta o `responseType` na request.

O problema não estava nesse ponto, sim na chamada da request, onde era feito o GET, faltava especificar o `responseType`.

O código funcionando fica assim:

```
$http.get('/api/download/' + uid, {responseType:'arraybuffer'});
```

Comment: Com esse método consegue fazer o download no IE?

Comment: @GuilhermePatriarca só do IE 10 pra cima.